# High level of fragmentation with MongoDB 2.2.1

Tags: mongodb

On a legacy system that is running MongoDB 2.2.1 we are running out of disk space due to excessively large database files. Our actual data size is just under 3 GB, with about 1.7 GB index size, but the storage size is over 70 GB. So, the storage to data+index ratio is close to factor 15. There are about 40 data files, most of which are at the 2 GB maximum file size.

We are contemplating to run a compact() or repair() to regain some of the unused space, but we are worried about the problem recurring soon after. It seems that the current configuration (pretty close to the default configuration) is not suitable for the database usage pattern of our application.

What other tools, diagnostics, remedies or configuration changes are available that could help MongoDB make better use of the disk space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WiredTiger](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/), used in MongoDB 3.0 and later, is much more efficient in terms of disk usage.

However, migrating from MongoDB 2.2 to 3.0 is going to be a huge leap.

Another option, assuming this is configured as a replica set, is to re-sync the Secondary nodes individually and then perform a failover. This will have the same affect as performing a repair without the downtime that would occur as a result of using the repairDatabase command.

Comment: Thanks @AdamHarrison. Sadly, this is coming to a head quickly for us, and MongoDB is creating additional 2 GB files almost every day now. Are there any major incompatibilities between 2.2 and 3.0 that would make this such a huge leap?

Comment: There are a number of significant changes going just from 2.6 to 3.0. Drivers (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/#upgrade-drivers) will likely need to be updated for all applications using this deployment, as well as finding the proper upgrade path for your database. You should review the upgrade requirements for each version (https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/release-notes/2.4-upgrade/). In the short term, you may want to look into the other compaction methods.